# Why is my shortcode only displaying one post rather than three posts?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

My short code is only displaying the third post rather than three posts.

What do I need to adjust to display a list of the three most recent posts?

````
function recent_posts_shortcode() {

    query_posts(array(
        'orderby'       => 'date', 
        'order'         => 'DESC', 
        'showposts'     => 3
    ));

    if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $return_string = '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
      endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();

    return '<ul>' . $return_string . '</ul>';    
}

add_shortcode('recent-posts', 'recent_posts_shortcode');```
````

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`query_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) which isn't intended for use in Plugins or Themes, and can **not** be used in "The Loop". You can make use of the [`WP_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class instead. It's instantiated almost exactly the same.

Also, the reason you're only getting the last post is because your code is re-assigning the `$return_string` variable each time. You'll need to use PHP's [concatenation assignment operator: `.=`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) instead. (Also, to avoid undefined variable warnings, you'll need to initialize it first, this is a great place to add the first `<ul>`

```
function recent_posts_shortcode(){
    $recent_posts_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'orderby' => 'date', 
        'posts_per_page' => 3
    ) );

    $return_string = '<ul>';

    if( $recent_posts_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $recent_posts_query->have_posts() ) : $recent_posts_query->the_post();
            $return_string .= sprintf( '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', esc_attr( get_permalink() ), get_the_title() );
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    $return_string .= '</ul>';
    return $return_string;
}

add_shortcode( 'recent-posts', 'recent_posts_shortcode' );
```